# Docker ps shows running container that I cannot stop or kill. How to stop/kill that container?

Tags: docker

"Docker p"s shows 1 running container. The command "docker ps --filter status=running" shows the same process.

When trying to stop the container, I get the identification but nothing happens. The container is still running.

When I performing a 'docker kill id' I get:

> Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: xyz: Container
>   2f-etc is not running

I cannot perform a 'docker container rm name' because of this message:

> Error response from daemon: driver "overlay2" failed to remove root
>   filesystem for
>   2f-etc:
>   remove
>   /var/lib/docker/overlay2/0877e30fd3a98f46b981827b52aec02a7004649e2a9c01c72e38cc8de5b309b0/diff/tmp/hsperfdata_root/5:
>   read-only file system

**How to stop / kill that container?**

What do I know more:

- It may be that I stopped my computer without stopping the container. I will take care ;-)
- I noticed also that creating a new image with 'docker build -t newname .' is failing because: Error response from daemon: mkdir /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder471922504: read-only file system

Comment: do `docker ps` without any argument

Comment: Yes, it shows that running container. Docker ps --filter status=running gives the same container. BUT ... I cannot stop or kill that container.

Comment: You may have to restart docker machine

Comment: Try `docker container rm -f name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Aderemi Dayo suggested - a restart of the Docker machine suffices.

Answer (score 14):

Restart docker is simple but global solution. In my case I needed to keep other containers working without stop and the solution of @juanlumn helped me, which is `docker container rm -f name` (it removes container).

Comment: This is crazy... this switch isn't documented in https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_stop/ , but it works! Thank you!

Comment: Didn't help in my case. Still banging my head on this. Only restart docker helps, but this is a painkiller, not a solution :(

Comment: Didn't help in my case either.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes `docker restart` doesn't work, so you may have to individually run `docker stop` & `docker start`. Thereafter use the `docker container rm <container>` command to remove.